# How Exactly Does ActiveRecord Expect dates to be Formatted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm writing some rails code to my `seeds.rb` file, and my model has a `date` field.  For example, I create an object like:

```
 Object.create[{name: 'foo', description: 'bar', when: '\Date.parse("17/9/2015")}]
```

and the only error I get is a `NoMethodError: undefined method to_f`.

Should I be inputting the date as a string instead of a Date object?  If so, how should it be formatted?  I've searched around for a couple hours, but all I have found are descriptions of DateTime and the Date module.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Alright I have confirmed that this is a WINDOWS ONLY issue.  When running rake commands after having installed rails via RailsInstaller, you must use `bundle exec rake ...` because RailsInstaller bundles gems oddly (at least according to  https://gist.github.com/KelseyDH/11198922).  This fixed my issue.

Answer (score 3):

Use an actual date instance:

```
Object.create[{
  name: 'foo',
  description: 'bar',
  when: Date.parse('17/9/2015')
}]
```

Not a string.

Comment: That's what I did.  However, when I ran `rake db:seed` I got the `undefined method to_f` error; I don't know what this means or how to fix it.  Do you know why I'd get this specific error?

Comment: Apparently rails is trying to convert an object to a float. Do your columns have the correct type in your schema file? Is your database clean?

Comment: It's a date in schema.rb file and when I ran rake db:seed using strings instead of Date objects it did fine.  At this point I just want to know why it won't accept the Date object.

Comment: Can you reset the database? If it works with strings it's quite possible the column was of the incorrect type when it was created.

Comment: I ran `rake db:reset` and it still worked only with strings; I thought this straight up dropped the table but do I need to reset the db manually?

Comment: Also when I reset the db with the date objects I got `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Date into String`

Comment: And when I reset using `Date.new` instead of `Date.parse` I got the `undefined method to_f` error again

Comment: There must be more to this problem. Try a naked application with `rails new`. Use sqlite. Use only 1 model. Add a model with string and date column. Seed. Does it work like you expect?

Comment: It worked fine.  I think there might be an issue with the rails install -- I'm on Windows and the only rails command that worked in the powershell console I was in was rails n *; I had to open a new window.

Comment: As per my comment above, this is pretty clearly a windows-only rails install issue.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have an syntax error here:

```
Object.create[{name: 'foo', description: 'bar', when: '\Date.parse("17/9/2015")}]
```

Change to:

```
Object.create(name: 'foo', description: 'bar', when: Date.parse("17/9/2015"))
```

But better to work with Date class:

```
Object.create(name: 'foo', description: 'bar', when: Date.new(2015, 9, 17))
```